# React useEffect Hook not called after redux State Change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have created a React.FunctionComponent that should act as a wrapper for children and that should do some stuff as soon as some redux dispatching stuff is done in Typescript but it doesn't work. I created the Wrapper:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useTypedSelector } from "../../Models/States";

const RoutingWrapper: React.FunctionComponent = ({children, ...rest }) => {

const state = useTypedSelector(state => state);

useEffect(() =>{
  if(state.routing.routingLoaded)
  {
     //doStuff
  }
},[state.routing])

...
return(...)

export {RoutingWrapper}
```

I get the useTypedSelector Hook from

```
import { useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import { RoutingStateInterface } from "./RoutingState"; //Just Types and Interfaces

export interface RootState {
  ...
  routing: RoutingStateInterface
}

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

after the component is rendered the redux magic takes place and I want the component to wait for the state change and then do some stuff. Do you have an idea why it's not calling useEffect after the state has changed? If I look at the state after everything is done I can see that the state has a value of true for state.routing.routingLoaded but it hasn't executed the useEffect with the doStuff part after it has been modified.

Adding a comparrison function for rerender like this didn't work:

```
const state = useTypedSelector(state => state,(()=>{return true}));
```

Any ideas or hints would be great :)

Thanks, Christian

Edit:

This is how I update the state:

```
let initialState: RoutingStateInterface = {
  routingLoaded: false,
  routes: {},
  currentRouting: undefined,
};

const loadRouting = (
  state: RoutingStateInterface,
  action: RoutingActions.RoutingAction
  ) => {
    switch (action.payload.name) {
      case "LoadRoutingPayload":
        const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        action.payload.body.map((item) => {
          newState.routes[item.path] = item;
        });
        newState.routingLoaded = true;
        return newState;
      default:
        return state;
     }
  };
```

Comment: have you tried logging the value of `state.routing` before and after state change, is it the same or different?

Comment: Hi @shubhamjha I used the redux dev tools and they tell me in the diff that before it was false and then changed to true

Comment: I have asked the value of `state.routing`, it can't be boolean right? because you also  have `routingLoaded` property in it, like `state.routing.routingLoaded`, you may try using `[state.routing.routingLoaded]` inside useEffect params

Comment: Ah, sorry. state.routing is an object with 3 children, state.routing.routingLoaded is a boolean

Comment: can you post the code when you change the state ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

It seems that changes within an Object are not properly watched so I decided to watch the exact key I need

```
const routingLoaded = useTypedSelector(state => state.routing.routingLoaded);

useEffect(() =>{
  if(routingLoaded)
  {
    //doStuff
  }
},[routingLoaded])
```

Now it's working the way it should :)